# P5.js in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, p5.js

I started learning p5.js some days ago, and now I wanted to use IntelliJ IDEA instead of the [p5.js online editor](https://editor.p5js.org). Most things like the `setup()`, `draw()` and `ellipse()` functions work as expected, but the `createCanvas()` function doesn't - it is underlined green and the error message says "Unresolved function or method createCanvas()".

I tried using VSCode, and there it worked perfectly, but I prefer to use IntelliJ, and so I wanted to know if and if yes how I can get it to work in IntelliJ.

```
<script src="p5.js"></script> //p5.js is the file with all the code from the official p5js.org homepage.
<script src="sketch.js"></script> //sketch.js is the file where my code that should be executed is located
```

```
function setup() { //The setup() function is recognized as expected,
    createCanvas(1000, 1000); //But the createCanvas() function isn't.
}
```

Comment: The `setup()` function isn't being "recognized" by IntelliJ; you're defining a function called `setup()`. There shouldn't be anything special about the `p5.js` library, so you should follow whatever steps you normally follow to load a JavaScript library in `IntelliJ`.

Comment: You can either download it from CDN (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_external_library_downloaded_from_CDN) or add non-minified p5.js file as a library (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_js_custom_third_party_library).

Comment: @KevinWorkman @Oksana Thanks for your reply, I have never loaded a library in IntelliJ, so I just followed the [link on the jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-javascript-libraries.html). But that didn't change anything, the `createCanvas()` function still isn't recognized. I also tried the downloading it from CDN, didn't work for me either. I assume that's some kind of bug from IntelliJ's side and am going to continue using VSCode.

Comment: @littlegamer757 I doubt it's a bug in IntelliJ. My guess is that JavaScript requires some setup that you haven't done. There are instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#ws_js_start_existing_app). But in the end you should use whatever editor you're comfortable with. I normally use a basic text editor when I'm working with JavaScript and P5.js.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I already configured everything listed in the guide

Answer (score 16):

p5 functions are defined as `p5.prototype.<function name> = function(){}`, so the IDE expects a namespace here... As a workaround, please try installing p5 typings: in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**, press **Downloads...**, select `p5` from the list. This should solve the problem

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Although downloading p5 from the Libraries list didn't solve the problem, I can live with writing p5.prototype in front of every function. I think the p5 from the Libraries list might not be the same p5 as I want to use. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @littlegamer757 Make sure you specify the Framework type as Prototype in the Libraries section and you won't need to do p5.prototype in your code...

Answer (score 5):

I used to mimic the p5js online editor in IntelliJ IDEA by using the [Live Edit](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7007-live-edit) plugin in combination with split screening Chrome and IntelliJ. The plugin will automatically update your HTML/JS in the Chrome window, s.t. you can instantly see the effects of your changes to your p5js code. It will only work when you run your HTML/JS file in debug mode.

Here's an example:

[image]